# Could anyone explain in detail whats happening in the part that is mention below?

Tags: formatting, string-formatting

`start_time = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(startHour, startMinute)`

this is the piece of code i dont understand...
it is for formatting the number..i know that
I want to get the result like "19:05". It gives me the result.

Can anyone tell me whats happening in this part?

```
{0:02d}:{1:02d}
```

Because it looks like {0:02d} is already in format of time i.e "H:M" then how come this code is replicated like {0:02d}:{1:02d}

Answer (score 0):

{0:02d} >> this is padding zero to the left if the length of your startHour variable is less than 2.

{1:02d} >> this is padding 1 to the left if the length of your startMinute variable is less than 2.